# Modal closes onMouseUp outside modal in react

Tags: reactjs, onclick, event-listener, react-functional-component

I have a div.modal-container DOM node which has a div.modal node, this modal closes when clicked anywhere outside of it. Inside this modal i have a draggable image which can we adjusted by the user. However when the user does onMouseDown inside this modal and drags it such that the mouse exits the modal and then triggers the onMouseUp event in the modal-container, the modal closes. Is there any way to prevent the closing of modal onMouseUp outside of the modal ?

the modal shouldn't have closed onMouseUp outside the modal.

```
function App() {
  const [modalState, setModalState] = useState(false);
  const modal = useRef();
  const closeModal = () => setModalState(false);
  const openModal = () => setModalState(true);
  return (
    <div className="modal-container" onClick={() => closeModal()}>
      {modalState ? (
        <div className="modal" onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} ref={modal}>
          <span className="close-button" onClick={(e) => closeModal()}>
            <b>X</b>
          </span>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <button
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            openModal();
          }}
        >
          Open Modal
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

codepen link for the said issue: https://codepen.io/kartikey09/pen/VwVYvMv

steps to recreate the issue:

1. click open modal,
2. press left click in the green modal that opened up.
3. drag the mouse to the grey modal-container div whilst pressing left click.
4. lift left click up.

Answer (score 0):

A click event is triggered by a single mousedown event followed by a corresponding mouseup event, all within the confines of the same element.

In your situation, you could employ the backdrop concept, much like the following example.

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [modalState, setModalState] = useState(false);
  const modal = useRef();
  const closeModal = ()=>setModalState(false);
  const openModal = ()=>setModalState(true);
  return (
    <div className="modal-container" >
      {!modalState && (
        <button
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            openModal();
          }}
        >
          Open Modal
        </button>
      )}
      {modalState && (
        <>
        <div className = "modal" onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} ref={modal}>
          <span className = "close-button" onClick={(e) => closeModal()}>
            <b>X</b>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div className="back-drop" onClick={() => closeModal()}></div>
          </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**CSS**

```
.modal{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  z-index: 100;
}

.close-button:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-container{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.back-drop {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 10;
}
```